# Improving JVM performance in a virtualized environment

Tags: java, jvm, vmware, xen

What are the points to consider in improving JVM performance in a virtualized environment (Vmware/XenServer)?

- Whare are the settings to improve JVM in a virtualized environement?
- Is there any JVM specially made for virtualized environment?
- Or is there a JVM that is used by a Java client and send bytecodes to a server and execute it from there?

Comment: Here are some [best practices](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008480) according to VMWare (pulled from a deleted answer). In general however there is no single answer to this question - you'll need to benchmark your application, identify hotspots and bottlenecks, and iterate.